# How to disable TTY echo in Python when STDIN is piped

Tags: python, echo, tty, ioctl

To use a command-line program with an interactive TTY, you just need to execute that program in a shell (of course, the program needs to do blocking I/O operations on STDIN/STDOUT). For example : `python -i`.

But you can also do this: `cat - | python -i`. This is useful to feed STDIN with a file first then with an interactive TTY. For example: `cat prelude.py - | python -i`. This way you get an interactive TTY **after** piping the whole content of the script into STDIN. I know there are other ways to load a script in the Python interactive shell, this is just an example.

I want to write a Python script that behave the same way. Here is my current testing script:

```
import os
import sys
import threading

def main():
    thread_loop = True
    def thread_func():
        unbuf_fd = os.fdopen(sys.stdin.fileno(), 'rb', 0)
        sys.stdin.close()
        sys.stdin = unbuf_fd
        unbuf_fd = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'wb', 0)
        sys.stdout.close()
        sys.stdout = unbuf_fd
        while(thread_loop):
            sys.stdout.write(sys.stdin.read(1))
        sys.stdout.write(b'Exiting...\n')
    def signal_func(sig, frame):
        global thread_loop
        print('You pressed Ctrl+C.')
        thread_loop = False
    forward_std = threading.Thread(target=thread_func, args=())
    forward_std.start()
    forward_std.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Both `python test.py` and `cat - | python test.py` work but unlike `python -i` i have an echo of what's poured into STDIN.

How can I disable this echo ? The following code works with `python test.py`:

```
fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
fd_attr = tty.tcgetattr(fd)
tty.setcbreak(fd)
```

But with `cat - | python test.py` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tata.py", line 33, in <module>
    main()
  File "tata.py", line 25, in main
    fd_attr = tty.tcgetattr(fd)
termios.error: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')
```

Is there a generic way to disable echo for STDIN wether it's piped or not ? Is there a specific way to disable echo for a piped STDIN and that I can use when `sys.stdin.isatty()` return `False`?

Thanks for your advice !

Comment: In the case `cat - | python test.py`, the Python script has no handle to the TTY (only to the pipe from `cat`), so it will be difficult to do anything about any keyboard echo. The only approach I can think of is to recursively go up the process tree to each parent, find out whether its stdin is a TTY from `/proc/PID/fd/0`, and if so, opening it and performing the appropriate ioctl. But it's an ugly hack that can and will go wrong in many situations. Why do you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: Note that `cat foo.py - | python -i` does _not_ output the contents of `foo.py` but it does echo keyboard input. You don't need to do anything special to get this behaviour.

Comment: "Why do you want to do this in the first place?" Well, I wanted to control what character from STDIN get to be printed to STDOUT but I was misunderstanding the link between STDIN and TTY. Thanks for your help.